# Creating a world map centered on another meridian in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a world map, but centered over the Pacific rather than the Prime Meridian. Recentering the projection (standard Mercator) on 180 degrees gives me a lot of ugly artifacts where countries are stretched across the "cut line" of the map.

I assume I need to do some kind of intentional clipping (like clipping to hemisphere with an orthographic projection), but I'm not sure how properly to make QGIS cut everything cleanly on a meridian. Is there a standard way of doing this? A plugin?

(I am using the Natural Earth 50m countries shapefile.)

Comment: like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167480/issue-rendering-polygons-at-global-scale-when-using-the-robinson-coordinate-refe

Comment: or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191491/seeking-shapefile-for-pacific-ring-of-fire

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those answer my question, as far as I can tell—I do not have geometries simplified, nor am I working with a raster layer.